# Laravel CSS File Cannot Be Read Unless Name is Changed

Tags: php, html, css, laravel

I have a css file located inside the public folder

```
public/components/css/main.css
```

In my home.blade.php file, it is referenced as

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="components/css/main.css">
```

But for some reason it cannot be referenced/read for that page but my other blade files can read the css file. When I try accessing the php page without Laravel, it can read the CSS file.

I tried changing the name of the CSS file in the directory to

```
public/components/css/test.css
```

and the link to

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="components/css/test.css">
```

And it works, my home.blade.php file can read the css! But then, the other blade files cannot read the CSS file which brings me back to the same problem despite having the same link to the css file.

This is very odd for me, am I doing something wrong here in Laravel?

Comment: What's also odd is when I keep the css file's name to main.css but refer to it as test.css on the link, it also works.

Answer (score 0):

You should either use the `asset()` function inside Laravel like this:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ URL::asset('components/css/main.css') }}">`

or refer to your files like this:

`<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/components/css/main.css">`

As I would assume that your issue is path related (based on the URI)

Comment: Still doesn't work unless I change the name of the css file.

Comment: I don't see how that would make a difference to be honest. Perhaps clear your caches?